# Why do npm or yarn download two versions of jquery?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

To explore the working principle of package manager of nodejs such as npm, yarn and cnpm, I did a test.

I found two packages: jquery-dreamstream and jquery.tree, and both of them only depend on jquery, no other dependencies.
jquery-dreamstream depends on jquery@^2.1.1
jquery.tree depends on jquery@~2.1.1

I run this command on terminal:

`npm i jquery-dreamstream jquery.tree -S`

It downloads three packages in /node_modules:

- jquery@2.2.4
- jquery-dreamstream
- jquery.tree

And in jquery.tree, there is a node_modules dir which contains jquery@2.1.4

So that is:

```
jquery@2.2.4
jquery-dreamstream
jquery.tree:{
    jquery@2.1.4
}
```

In fact it downloaded 4 packages.

This result confuses me.

Why does npm download two versions of jquery?

Why does not npm only download jquery@2.1.4? I thinks this version can be used by jquery-dreamstream and jquery.tree at the same time, because 2.1.4 satisfies both ^2.1.1 and ~2.1.1

Comment: Well, the `^` and `~` have different semantics, so the dependencies aren't strictly the same. You are right that `2.1.4` should satisfy both but it's also possible that NPM doesn't want to make that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Because `jquery.tree` lists `"jquery": "~2.1.1"` in its `package.json` as a `dependency`. This will install the version only for this package. The behaviour you expected (installing ONE version which fits all requirements) would have been the case if it had been listed in the `peerDependencies` of `jquery.tree`. In this case you would have needed to add `jquery` to your own `dependencies` so you can decide on the version. Using peer dependencies is currently considered best practice, though `jquery.tree` is 5 years old so it might be due to its age that it does not conform to this.

Answer (score 0):

use resolutions in package.json, can make u only install one version

https://yarnpkg.com/docs/selective-version-resolutions/